# Is the unix permissions execute bit redundant?

Tags: permissions

If a user already has read and write permissions on a file, can't they just copy the contents of the file, delete it, and recreate it allowing execute permissions for themselves? Does a lack of 'x' bit ever stop a user from being able to execute the contents of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And if the user is the owner of the file, they can set it to be readable and then read, even if there were no read permission. And they can set it to be writeable and edit it. And they can remove it if they are able to have writeable bit to the containing directory. So "w" and "r" bits seem useless too, following your logic.

Those are called *file modes*, not just *permissions* for a reason. They only become permissions when we talk about the access of *other* users to given file.

There is usually no problem is user runs a program. It is, finally, why the computers exist, for users to be able to run programs. Sometimes users write their own programs (or scripts) themselves and they might need to be able to build and run them. The system must be designed so the program running under ordinary user privileges can't do much harm to other users. Some programs are more privileged (some can be SUID, for example), but user can't create such a program themselves, they need a superuser to set a sensitive special mode bit on a file.

However, if your goal is to create a very confined environment which won't let users run arbitrary programs but only those you've installed as an admin, you need to use additional measures. Those measures include:

- Mounting all user-writeable directories (homes, tmp and so on) as no-execute, so user can't create an "executable" file. However, this doesn't prevent it fully; user still run their own scripts prefixed with installed interpreters, and often this is enough to do anything they want.
- Using mandatory access controls like SELinux. This is very secure, however, cumbersome as well.